# Firestore: How to query for specific timestamp (equality)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I would like the following query to work

```
await admin.firestore().collectionGroup(`calenders`).where('appointments', 'array-contains', admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now)).get()
```

I have debug data to test with

```
const testDate= new Date(2000, 3, 3, 23, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(testDate)
console.log(admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(testDate))
```

Also I printed the timestamp of the document which matches the testDate in the exact same way.

```
Output for test date:
2000-03-03T23:00:00.000Z 
Timestamp { _seconds: 952124400, _nanoseconds: 0 }

Output for real document date
2000-03-03T23:00:00.000Z 
Timestamp { _seconds: 952124400, _nanoseconds: 0 }
```

This is clearly the same. Now I checked. To compare timestamps there is a method called `isEqual(Timestamp other)`. Does this mean there is no way to make the query work besides storing the timestamp in another dataformat?

Comment: I think the problem in your query is something else, you are trying to get date from an array and you are comparing the dates in there with a date generated as a `date.now()` I assume, is this correct? If so, you are never going to get any results in a `array-contains` as it's basically trying to get an equal date, up to milliseconds. I would suggest you to change your `appointments` array into a subcollection, that way you could query it with a date internal, which would be more assertive.

Comment: Thank for the reply. But indeed I query with the EXACT timestamp that is stored in the database (Basically I only query full hours). Every timestamp in the appointments array is in the format 0 s 0 ns and the full date. The Output of the debug data above shows this. The timestamp value indeed is exactly the same, so the query running this should return that specific document. Meanwhile I changed my backend to store the data as epoch seconds. This way the query works perfectly. So it seems that the API lags the possibility to query for equality on timestamps -> Is this a bug?

Comment: I would say that there might be some difference in the objects that is not related to the actual dates then, not sure if this is expected behaviour or not, but you could open a Bug Report in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) so that they can determine if this is expected or not.